# Issue with group permissions when dowloading files from browser on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, files, users, 22.04

Summary: I cannot download files in folders I have group permissions, but not ownership, when I download from two different browsers.

The system is an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.
This looks like a bug.

Detailed description of the issue:
I have two users, user1 and user2 on my machine.
Both user1 and user2 have their groups user1group and user2group.
Both user1 and user2 are members of both groups.

I am usually logged in as user1.
I create a folder named test_folder.
Then I change group ownership to user2group.
This folder has owner user1, group user2group and permissions for group.

user1 has access and can do whatever they want (through command line or regular interface).
But when I try to download a file from either firefox or chrome the file is not saved. On firefox I also get an error: permissions denied, which is coming from the "Files" application.

I tried the exact same thing on another machine I have with Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked fine. No issue at all. In both cases I just created a test folder in desktop and changed group of the folder.

It seems to be a "Files" permission issue somehow.

I am wondering if someone can reproduce this.
Please help.

Comment: No, it's a snap confinement issue re: Firefox.

Comment: Are  you sure? Firefox is in snap but Chrome also cant download in the folder and I didnt install it through snap.